# angular material chips placeholder float up instead of getting attached at the end

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, material-components

I am trying to use Angular material Chips. chips are working properly but there is an issue with a placeholder.

> my expected behavior for a placeholder is placeholder attaching at the end of the chips list
>   like [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUTOR.png). 
>  placeholder behavior that I am getting is [placeholder floating above list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BP0h.png).

```
        <mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
            <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Senders list">
                <mat-chip *ngFor="let sender of Senders"
                [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(sender)">
                {{sender}}
                    <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                </mat-chip>
                <input placeholder="add sender..."
                        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                        [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                        (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
            </mat-chip-list>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved,

I am using angular material version 8.2.3 in which place holder is floating above while in material 9 it is after list.